# Detect theme change when coming from dormant state in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, themes, lifecycle

I am using the following code in my app to detect the theme of the phone and set icons accordingly. But when I put my app to background then change the theme of phone later retrieve the app to foreground, the theme change is not detected. How do I detect the change of theme.

here is my code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   DarkThemeVisibility = (Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"];
   LightThemeVisibility = (Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"];
}
```

Comment: whilst this awesome from a user experience perspective, it is worth remembering that it isn't a requirement for certification into the store; merely that you *should* (NB not **must**) reflect the current theme when starting

Answer (score 1):

When you change the theme and go back to your app you will notice that the only thing which change color is the application bar. The application theme don't actually change before you restart the application (this is because application resources are loaded on application startup) so I don't think you need to change any icons in that case (since the color of your app has not changed).
If the icons you were changing were the icons of button app bar you should not need to either, normally your app bar icons should [use a white foreground on a transparent background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431806%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and they will automatically be colored according to the theme.

Comment: There is no way it can be changed? Because my app background looks odd when the app bar color changes!

Comment: You could do the contrary and force the Background and Foreground color of the Application bar to be the same as PhoneForegroundColor and PhoneBackgroundColor, like this the app bar color will not change either until the app is restarted (might just be a small performance impact of doing so..).